Is there a way to ignore inherited tests with vstest.console.exe?
ABC.Item1.Tests & ABC.Item2.Tests references ABC.Common.Tests.
When running vstest.console.exe ABC.Item1.Tests it runs the tests from itself & ABC.Common.Tests.
This is the same for ABC.Item2.Tests.
Meaning, that when I automatically run all test solutions; the tests in ABC.Common.Tests get run 3 times.
Is there a way to ignore the inherited tests?
